# When Converting Lead to Account, is it possible to update the parentId of a query?

Tags: controller, leads, lead-conversion, custom, id

When I create a list on a Lead, and then I convert the Lead to an Account, the list I created can not populate in my custom VF page because my logic is pulling the parentId. Is there a way to update a parentId to be the AccountId once a Lead has been converted?

APEX

```
public noteandtaskcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
    actId = controller.getId(); 
    List<myController> wrappers = new List<myController>(); 

    //if (convert happens) {
    //    ParentId = AccountId;
    //}

    record1 = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body, CreatedDate From Note WHERE ParentId =: actId OR Id=: actId];
    for (SObject rec2 : record1) {
         wrappers.add(new myController(rec2, 'CreatedDate'));  
    }           
    wrappers.sort();
    sortedRecords = new List<SObject>(); 
    for (myController wrapper : wrappers) sortedRecords.add(wrapper.record);
    system.debug('this is the list: ' + wrappers);
```

VisualForce

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sortedRecords}" var="record">
        <apex:column headerValue="Title/Subject">
            <apex:variable var="field" value="{!IF(BEGINS(record.Id, '002'), 'Title', 'Subject')}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!record[field]}" />
        </apex:column>
```

My Lead Page:
[image]

My converted Lead Page:
[image]

As you can see no notes are transferred over. I believe this is because I define the parentId when I create the note in the Lead page. Then the note is transferred over to the Account page. When I run my code for the account page it is asking for all notes with the parentId that matches the current page's Id. Because the note's parentId is already assigned, the new account page will not pick up this note and will not display it.

*UPDATE*
When I query Notes before I convert, all of my notes are returned.
When I convert my Lead, and then I query my account, no notes are returned.
[SELECT (Select CreatedById, Title, Body, CreatedDate From Notes) FROM Account WHERE Id= '123456789']
When I manually add in a new note on the Account page and then I do the same query, I am returned one result.

*UPDATE*
The notes are being converted from Lead to Account. The picture below is the Account page with the list of notes that were converted. When I call my custom controller to display all of the notes in my custom VF page, it does not register because the ParentId has already been set. To clarify my custom VF page is embedded in my Account page. It is a second area to view the notes.

[image]

Comment: Use Developer Console and query the `Note`s that were transferred on Lead Conversion to inspect their values - then post results using [edit]. I'm also assuming that the controller you posted is for a custom component on your Account VF page

Comment: @SantanuBoral yes, I am using a custom controller

Comment: It has to be something along the lines of an If statement saying: IF the current page starts with '001' then also add these notes to the custom VF page

Comment: [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm&language=en_US) suggests Notes aren't transferred on Lead Conversion

Comment: @cropredy I do know that they are being converted. I can see all of the notes in the Account page. See edits. My issue is pulling these notes into a custom VF page inside of the account page.